# Delete all records in the usermeta wordpress table except for specific ID's

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am using Gravity Forms add on "User Registration". It adds extra meta data fields to the users. Over time and I guess changes that have been made has created more meta data than is needed.

There are fields like "mail-a", "mail-A", and "Mail_A". I want to start over and get rid of all this metadata but I do not want to erase 2 of the users (ID's).

What would I put in the Query field in phpMyAdmin to accoplish this for the Wordpress table wp_usermeta?

Comment: What database access do you have? If you have access to error queries you could just do a delete query where is not equal to the id's you want to keep. So do you have access to query the database?

Answer (score 0):

Depending if you have database access to perform queries you could execute the following query:

```
Delete from user_table where Id not in (1,2,3)
```

Replace the name of the table to correspond to the table you which to delete the records. And replace 1,2 and 3 with the actual id's you want to keep.